# GCD of $p+q$ for all pairs of primes $p,q$ of the form $p-q=12n+2x$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, prime-gaps

I came across this result, and i'm having trouble explaining it. I use it as an argument in a proof, so i need to explain this behavior, in the shortest possible way, and most importantly prove that this is true for all possible pairs of odd prime $p,q$, with $p>q>3$.

Any pair of primes $p,q$ that satisfy $p-q=12n$ also satisfies $p+q\equiv0\pmod2$.
Any pair of primes $p,q$ that satisfy $p-q=12n+2$ also satisfies $p+q\equiv0\pmod{12}$.
Any pair of primes $p,q$ that satisfy $p-q=12n+4$ also satisfies $p+q\equiv0\pmod{6}$.
Any pair of primes $p,q$ that satisfy $p-q=12n+6$ also satisfies $p+q\equiv0\pmod{4}$.
Any pair of primes $p,q$ that satisfy $p-q=12n+8$ also satisfies $p+q\equiv0\pmod{6}$.
Any pair of primes $p,q$ that satisfy $p-q=12n+10$ also satisfies $p+q\equiv0\pmod{12}$.

In other words:

```
p-q     gcd (p+q)
___________
0       2
2       12
4       6
6       4
8       6
10      12
12      2
14      12
16      6
18      4
20      6
22      12
24      2
26      12
28      6
30      4
32      6
34      12
```

Comment: Hi, what happened to your tool ? No feedback ? And did you search "ec-primes" yourself ?

Comment: Hi ! Sorry i got very busy lately, i'll take a look this weekend. I did search myself. I'll update and restart the tool, and i will include some stats in the page so we can see the progress. I know 0 < n < 209753 is verified for candidates only, and something like  0 < n < 95000 for any n.

Comment: To your question : The second claim has counterexamples when $q=3$, but it could be true for $p>q>3$

Comment: yes i forgot i noticed also, thank you

Comment: Part $1$ is trivial : Since $p$ and $q$ are both odd, $p+q$ must be even. We do not even need $p-q=12n$. When $p-q$ is not divisible by $3$ , then one of the primes must be of the form $3k+1$ and the other of the form $3k+2$, hence the sum must be divisible by $3$. What remains is the analysis modulo $4$, which should easily finish the proof.

Comment: In fact, if $p-q$ is not divisible by $4$, one of the primes must have the form $4k+1$ and the other the form $4k+3$, hence the sum is divisible by $4$.

Comment: It's certainly correct and the fastest way is probably what @orlp wrote, just bruteforce all the cases in residue class $\pmod{12}$. Something like
$$
p\equiv q+10 \pmod{12} \implies (p,q)\pmod{12}\in\{(11,1),(5,7)\} \implies p+q\equiv 0\pmod{12}
$$
(i.e. trying all $q$ and see if $p$ is valid $\pmod{12}$.)
Not sure about neatest / shortest way though.

Comment: You can also "cheat" a little by symmetry. For example
$$
p-q=12n+10 \implies q-p = -12n-10 = 12(-n-1) +2 = 12m+2
$$
So you can just reuse the result for $p-q=12n+2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to approach the $12n + 2$ case. I believe you can use this technique for all cases.

All primes are of the form $6k + 1$ or $6k + 5$. That means modulo $12$ all primes must have remainder $1, 5, 7$ or $11$.

When $p - q = 12n + 2$ there are two possibilities. Either $p = 12k + 7$ and $q = 12j + 5$ or $p = 12k + 1$ and $q = 12j + 11$. And in both cases it holds:

$$p + q \equiv 12k + 7 + 12j + 5 \equiv 0  \mod 12$$
$$p + q \equiv 12k + 1 + 12j + 11 \equiv 0  \mod 12$$

Comment: I'll give it a little more time but it seems to be the right approach